# redshift error: You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: amazon-redshift

ERROR: operator does not exist: super -> "unknown"
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.

SELECT e.created, e.updated, e.id, e.type,
coalesce(
case
when((e.data -> 'event_details')::varchar ->> 'c_serial') is null and (e.data ->> 'i_serial') is null and ((e.data -> 'event_details')::varchar ->> 's_serial') is null then null
else
CASE
WHEN ((e.data -> 'event_details'::text) ->> 'c_serial'::text) IS NOT NULL THEN (e.data -> 'event_details'::text) ->> 'c_serial'::text
ELSE
CASE
WHEN ((e.data -> 'event_details'::text) ->> 's_serial'::text) IS NOT NULL THEN (e.data -> 'event_details'::text) ->> 's_serial'::text
ELSE e.data ->> 'i_serial'::text
END
END
END) AS c_serial
from event e